# Locked tomcat threads

Tags: java, tomcat

My tomcat server is responding slowly frequently and dying out after some time. This is happening quite often once a week. I took a thread dump and it shows about 50% of the threads are in locked state. Class which is locking the thread is  `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint`
I think over the time number of thread locking is rising and finally taking up all threads in locked state.
Here is one statement from the thread dump which shows locked state

```
"http-8080-4" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000006acca800 nid=0x9d8 in Object.wait() [0x000000007083f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000028ead838> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.await(AprEndpoint.java:1511)
    - locked <0x0000000028ead838> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Comment: what tomcat version are you using (major and minor number please). Looks like a bug.

Comment: Angelo's suggestion has my vote.  If possible get the latest release version of everything - Tomcat, Java, and the Tomcat APR libraries, maybe even Apacahe HTTPD (since the libraries connect).  Also, if you're using the old mod_jk swtich to mod_proxy_ajp.

Comment: Feel free to switch to `mod_proxy_ajp` but `mod_jk` certainly isn't "old": it supports a lot of features that `mod_proxy_ajp` does not, and tends to have a quicker release cycle.